# Confusion between molecular weight and molecular mass

Tags: thermodynamics, particle-physics, kinetic-theory

Why is molecular weight not molecular mass × g? Because, mass and weight are different. Weight is the force with which you are being pulled, so molecular weight should not mean molecular mass, but why does it do so?

Comment: That nomenclature was invented a long time ago, so it is not going to be redefined now.